# ActionBar Not showing on device

Tags: android, android-studio, android-actionbar, youtube-api, android-theme

In Android Studio, i'm developing an app that requires the YouTube Data API to be used. I am able to get the API to work, however since the actionbar no longer shows on the device. In the Emulator, however, it shows the action bar. If i extend the "ActionBarActivity" it causes the app to crash because the "YouTubeBaseActivity" needs to be extended. Is there anyway I can extend both of these, or is there a better work around? My code is below.

```
public class MainActivity extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener{




    public static final String API_KEY = "AIzaSyDWOPhdnXxg0tBLPNDvdRJYtEXgxjUDV-g";
    public static final String PlayList_ID = "PLIcQhhPfl0XazBc9_KwIGpvTmm7hECIbI";
    private YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer;
    private YouTubePlayerFragment youTubePlayerFragment;
    private YouTubePlayerView youTubePlayerView;
    private MyPlayerStateChangeListener myPlayerStateChangeListener;
    private MyPlaybackEventListener myPlaybackEventListener;

    private static final int RQS_ErrorDialog = 1;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);




        youTubePlayerView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtubeplayerview);
        youTubePlayerView.initialize(API_KEY, this);


        myPlayerStateChangeListener = new MyPlayerStateChangeListener();
        myPlaybackEventListener = new MyPlaybackEventListener();


    }
```

In the activity_main.xml, the actionbar shows up on the emulator, but not my device. Any help would be much appreciated, as I couldn't find an answer to this anywhere else. Thanks!

Comment: The `actionBar` for the `app` or `actionBar` for the `youtube video` while playing? If the former, you should set the style/app theme that has actionBar. If the the latter one, you can check the code [here](https://github.com/jbj88817/YoutubeSample-android) referring to `Overlay ActionBar Demo`.

Answer (score 0):

There's a better way. Instead of using the YouTubeBaseActivity, use the [YouTubePlayerFragment](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayerFragment) which does not require you to use YouTube's activity.

After that, I recommend using the Toolbar on your own activity that extends AppCompatActivity. You can find a tutorial on how to set the toolbar [here](http://mateoj.com/2015/06/21/adding-toolbar-and-navigation-drawer-all-activities-android/)

Comment: After I do that, however, I get a bunch of errors saying "Cannot resolve method"? How do I fix this?

Comment: You cannot simply replace YouTubeActivity with YouTubePlayerFragment. You have to create a new file that extends YouTubePlayerFragment and attach it to your activity. Take a look at the [android documentation for fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

Comment: Sorry to ask, but would you mind helping me with this? I'm not the greatest when it comes to Java and if you could help me with this, then i'd know for future reference. Thank you!